# SQL: If no rows found, do another search?

Tags: sql

I need to write a query which would always return something, even if nothing satisfies conditions, something like this

```
SELECT * WHERE date > NOW() FROM table ORDER by date
   IF none is returned THEN
      SELECT FIRST FROM table ORDER by date
```

So only numbers more then 10 will be returned, if none is returned, return any number
Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: http://www.functionx.com/sqlserver/sql/case.htm

Comment: Please show the table schema and some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, using `union all`:

```
select *
from table
where number > 10
union all
(select *
 where number > 0 and
       not exists (select * from table where number > 10)
 limit 1
)
```

If you are using a reasonable version of SQL, you could do something like:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(number) over () as maxnumber,
             row_number() over (order by number desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where (maxnumber > 10 and number > 10) or seqnum = 1
```

You need window functions for this.

Comment: First one looks promising:) Is it possible to do it without repeating "select * from table where number > 10" twice in same query?

Comment: That depends on the database you are using.  The second version, for instance, has only one `where` clause.